# running two firefox instances -- one locally and another through ssh

Tags: firefox, ssh, remote-access

I would like to have two firefox instances running at the same time in my laptop, one locally and another opening an instance through an ssh connection to another computer.

If I just try to open the ssh'ed instance, it gets gobbled up into my existing local instance (opens a new tab), and I cannot access the remote disks, since it's just a new tab in the local instance, to upload pictures through a web page, for example.

If I just close the local instance and call firefox from ssh, then I can open it remotely, but I cannot open it locally, gets associated to the remote instance again.

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run Firefox with:

```
firefox -no-remote
```

This prevents Firefox from opening URLs in a running instance. You can also specify a profile path:

```
firefox -no-remote -profile /path/to/ffprofile
```

Or if the profile is within your profile folder `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxx.name`:

```
firefox -no-remote -P name
```